# dd Command Becoming Non-Resposive While Writting Floppy Image

Tags: 16.10, dd, floppy

I am trying to write a floppy image using `dd`. I am running this command:

`dd if=fdboot.img of=/dev/fd0 bs=1024 conv=sync status=progress ; sync`

(Though I've also tried a simple `dd if=fdboot.img of=/dev/fd0 status=progress` and gotten the same result.)

However, when `dd` gets to about 300KB-700KB written, it just stops. The drive activity light stays lit, and the drive continues to make noise (only disk noise, no head activity noise), but `dd` shows no more data being written. I've left it for over an hour doing this, but it never finishes, or moves any further. Considering it moves the first few hundred KB in about a minute it should certainly not take that long. I've also tried several different disks. Any ideas? Bad drive?

I'm on Ubuntu 16.10, BTW.

Comment: Can I ask why you're still using floppy disks?

Comment: My hobby is messing with old computers. I just built a Pentium Pro 200 system from parts and need to get an OS on it. Don't think the BIOS on the machine would boot to a SCSI CD-ROM drive very well, and that's not even taking into account that none of the operating systems from 1996 were released on bootable CDs.

Comment: Ah, OK. I don't think the disks are the issue, rather the drive itself. Do you have another to try maybe?

Comment: Just swapped out the Panasonic for an older NEC, same issue. This time it got to 1MB before it stopped. Now I'm starting to wonder if it's the image or maybe even the motherboard's floppy controller. Maybe I'll try a different distro too. This isn't the first problem I've had with 16.10

Comment: I'm honestly surprised that a late 2016 OS has any floppy support at all. Maybe try 12.04 or 14.04, although the former is close to losing support.